# Drawing text in PythonMagick?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, jpeg, watermark

How can I drawing text in PythonMagick? I need add watermark to JPG files, but I can't find any example on Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to use the `Image.composite()` method to layer the watermark image on top of the target image:

```
import PythonMagick

sample = PythonMagick.Image('sample.jpg')
watermark = PythonMagick.Image('watermark.jpg')

sample.composite(watermark, 50, 50,
                 PythonMagick.CompositeOperator.AtopCompositeOp)

sample.write('output.jpg')
```

**EDIT**

After looking more closely at PythonMagick, I would strongly advise against using it, as its API is quite hard to use and there is no python-friendly documentation. Instead, I would recommend using the [Python Imaging Library](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/). Here's a basic watermarking example:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont, ImageEnhance

image = Image.open('sample.jpg'))
font = ImageFont.truetype('/usr/share/fonts/TTF/DejaVuSans.ttf', 20)
watermark = Image.new('RGBA', (120, 25), (255, 255, 255))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(watermark)
draw.text((5, 0), 'Watermark', (0, 0, 0), font)
mask = ImageEnhance.Brightness(watermark).enhance(0.2)
image.paste(watermark, (25, 25), mask)
image.save('output.jpg')
```

Comment: Thanks, but what can i do, if i need to add text, not picture.

Comment: @user999058. See my edited answer for a better approach to your problem. You might also find [this recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/362879-watermark-with-pil/) useful.